# How (in TortoiseSVN) do I update my Working copy to a past revision without losing any versions?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

SVN newbie (although so far I really like it (coming from CVS)

Ok, here's my scenario:

I had:

1. Version x
2. Then I copied a set of old files over the top of those
3. Checked them in and created a Tag ("OldVersion")
4. I now want to revert back to version X while still preserving "OldVersion")

It seems like something *like* a [BackMerge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo) might do it but that would lose my changes (I think)

I naively tried *Update to Revision...*  but apparently that' really more to "peek" at what things looked like in that Revision.

Any suggestions?

(The obvious is to get a copy of Version X and copy it over the Revision at tag "OldVersion" and continue on my merry way, but I'd like to do this the "proper way" and maybe learn something here).

Comment: Once something is committed to the repo, you can't remove it or accidentally overwrite it unless you really really try hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you did your step 3 as one commit, then you should be able to do the following:

- Right click on your workspace directory and use TortoiseSVN -> Show Log
- Select the 'old version' revision you committed and right click and 'revert changes from this revision'
- Commit

This will perform a reverse merge. This is described in the svn manual under  [Undoing Changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo).